# window.scroll events triggering twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, custom-scrolling

No matter what method I use to detect scrolling on the page the event is triggered twice. Please see the code for the different methods I have tried.

```
<body onmousewheel="alert('Why are you alerting twice?')">
```

or

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).scroll(function(){
    alert("Why are you alerting twice?");
});
</script>
```

or

```
window.onscroll = please_scroll;

function please_scroll() {
      alert("Why are you alerting twice?");
    }
```

I have even tried using $.debounce.

In case it is of any use I will explain what I am trying to do:
When the user scrolls the wheel either up or down, the page will animate the scroll to the next full width content div. I have code that is successfully doing this onclick of my menu, but I would also like it to happen as the user scrolls, essentially auto assisting them with scrolling to each part of my page. This is the function I currently have for scrolling:

```
function scrollTo(id){
  // Scroll
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top - 110},'slow',function(){
    animation_active = "false";
  });
}
```

Comment: firstly, should be: `window.onscroll = please_scroll;` Secondly, you shouldn't use alert to debug event

Comment: well the mousewheel and other hids like the apple mouses can trigger scroll events more often when being used. you have to use a timeout for that

Answer (score 19, accepted):

many devices can trigger scroll events which appear to happen once more often. simply use a timeout for that:

```
var timeout;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);  
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        // do your stuff
    }, 50);
});
```

you can play with the value 50, i recommend something between 50 and 150.

Comment: I just spent 4 hours trying to debug this and you seem to have resolved my issues straight up. Wow. Thanks!

Comment: LOL me too! I did not think a timeout would be needed, my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383804/why-is-my-eventlistener-getting-called-twice?noredirect=1#comment52639143_32383804

Comment: Working but with delay!, not immediate

Comment: @WantToDo decrease the 50 to whatever floats your boat