# Why is my EventListener getting called twice?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom-events, addeventlistener, infinite-scroll

In my Angular mobile app ([Ionic framework](http://ionic.io/)), I'm setting up my infinite scroll functions. It's basically the same code as the dashboard version yet my `scrollTagsPanel` gets called twice.

**getTagsFactory**
Inside my `getTagsFactory` I do an API call and retrieve back tag objects, then I pass the tags into the `getTagsColHeight` function inside of `tagsPanelDirective`:

```
tagsPanelCtrl.tagsPanel.totalTags = data.data.ticker_tags_rows;
tagsPanelCtrl.tagsPanel.tagsLoaded = true;
tagsPanelCtrl.tagsPanel.getTagsColHeight(tagsPanelCtrl.tagsPanel.tags);
```

**tagsPanelDirective**

Here are the only 2 methods responsible for the infinite scroll.
`getTagsColHeight` checks to make sure that the `tags` array is not empty, then it simply adds the event `scroll` to the function `scrollTagsPanel`.

The calculation to determine if the height of the tags column `tagsCol` has reached a point that matches it's height is in `scrollTagsPanel`.

```
function getTagsColHeight(tags) {
    if (tags.length != 0 || tags.length != undefined) {
        $timeout(function() {
            tagsCol.addEventListener('scroll', scrollTagsPanel);
        });
    }
}

function scrollTagsPanel(event) {
    // Reached bottom of tags panel:
    console.log('tagsCol height: ', tagsCol.offsetHeight);
    console.log('scrolled point: ',(tagsCol.scrollHeight - tagsCol.scrollTop));

    if ((tagsCol.scrollHeight - tagsCol.scrollTop) === tagsCol.offsetHeight) {
        if (!vm.limitReached) {

            vm.start += vm.limit;
            vm.tagsLoaded = false;

            if ((vm.start + vm.limit) > vm.totalTags) {
                vm.limitReached = true;
                console.log('vm.limitReached = true!', vm.limitReached);
            }

            console.log('scrollTagsPanel...');
            loadTags();
        }
    }
}
```

What scroll step produces 2 calls with the exact same data:

[image]

I `console.log(event)` and I see 1 `Event {}` and 1 `CustomEvent {}`, does this help?

[image]

---

**UPDATE** - ok I can get the event to first just once if I click on the column, so I guess it's detecting a click and scroll at the same time when I scroll?

Below, I scrolled once, and then clicked twice afterwards:

[image]

Comment: I think it could depend on your mouse / touchpad. Check it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22018607/636478

Comment: @latata whoa! lol I did not think that would work, but it did! :D perhaps because I'm working inside of the Ionic mobile app framework, that's why it gets called twice there and not in the desktop dashboard browser version, hmmm.. want to post the answer? You can copy his, I converted it into an Angular `$timeout` version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var timeout;

tagsCol.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    clearTimeout(timeout);  
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        scrollTagsPanel();
    }, 50);
});
```

According to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22018607/636478

---

Adding the AngularJS version:

```
tagsCol.addEventListener('scroll', function () {
    $timeout.cancel(vm.scrollEventTimer);
    clearTimeout(vm.scrollEventTimer);
    vm.scrollEventTimer = $timeout(function() {
        scrollTagsPanel();
    }, 50);
});
```